# How do I pass a python string to Linux Command Line?

Tags: python

```
import time
start_time = time.time()
for i in range (0, 10000):
    print('openssl rsautl -encrypt -pubin -inkey public.pem -in message.txt -out message_enc.txt')
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

I want to pass the string within the print method to the Linux command line and run it to get the average encryption time of RSA. I can not seem to figure out how to do this though. I could only find out how to pass arguments from the command line into a Python script.

Comment: `import os; os.system('ls -lrt')`

Comment: @itsneo, please don't encourage that. `os.system()` is deprecated in favor of `subprocess`, and invoking a shell unnecessarily is bad practice (not only inefficient, but often leads to security bugs).

Comment: Thanks for linking similar posts. I had no idea to use those keywords. I never want to create duplicate posts. Sometimes I just do not know good keywords to search for.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the [`subprocess` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html), which is built-in to Python.

```
>>> subprocess.call(["ls", "-l"])
0
```

Comment: See "Answer Well-Asked Questions" in [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Questions which "have already been asked and answered many times before" should be closed, not answered.